# getSectionFromURL.py is now depreciated in Plone 4

Tags: plone

I was reading from the Weblion Sprint of 10/2011 that:

"However, theming folders below root proved to be somewhat problematic as getSectionFromURL.py is now depreciated in Plone 4."

source: https://weblion.tlt.psu.edu/FogBugz/default.asp?pg=pgWikiDiff&ixWikiPage=944&nRevision1=1

I used this all the time in Plone 3. Does anyone know of an "easy" method to target subfolders in Plone 4?

Answer (score 1):

The section body class is still given the folder id, it just doesn't use the getSectionFromURL method anymore to do that, it uses:

```
plone_view.bodyClass(template, view)
```

and to get plone_view

```
plone_view context/@@plone
```

Comment: How is it not enough information? This is how it's done in the new sunburst theme. Unless you mean you used getSectionFromURL in your python code, then you'll need to use the getMultiAdapter method to grab the plone_view utility.

Comment: Yes, I used python code so that Plone could understand the stylesheet. For Example, if I had a folder called Chinese and a folder inside that called calendar, I could target that using section-chinese-calendar. I am just looking for a way to replicate that ability in Plone 4.

Answer (score 0):

with default sunburst theme you only get body.section-chinese (for the top level folder plone/chinese/calendar) and in addition some other classes on the body tag:

- template-document-view (for the currently used template or view)
- portaltype-document (for the content type of the current context)

if this is not enough information for you to style the calendar properly, you need to either

a) code your own @@plone view (for your skin layer) that adds the functionality you previously had in your getSectionFromURL method  or

b) still use your old getSectionFromURL script and adapt the main_template accordingly

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is customize getSectionFromURL as per http://www.uwosh.edu/ploneprojects/docs/how-tos/how-to-make-plone-generate-.section-css-classes

Customise 'getSectionFromURL' (from plone_scripts)

Edit the last line from:

```
 return "section-" + contentPath[0]
```

to:

```
 return " ".join(["section-" + "-".join(contentPath[:d+1]) for d in range(len(contentPath))])
```

Then customize your main_template by changing the line

```
              body_class python:plone_view.bodyClass(template, view);
```

to

```
              body_class here/getSectionFromURL;
```

Comment: I can't find the file 'getSectionFromURL' in plone_scripts in Plone 4. It doesn't exist?

Comment: It's in plone_deprecated now